# How can change the color of the display?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a very basic timer, but I was wondering if there was any way I could change the display color to red when the timer reaches 10 seconds. I tried placing this code in various places within the javascript to try and place a class inside the element, but it just screws it up.

```
if (secondsRemaining <== 10) {
  timeDisplay.className += "red";
}
```

Here's my javascript:

```
  var secondsRemaining; 
  var intervalHandle;

  function resetPage() {
    document.getElementById("inputArea").style.display = "block";
  }

  function tick() {

    var timeDisplay = document.getElementById("time");
    var min = Math.floor(secondsRemaining / 60); 
    var sec = secondsRemaining - (min * 60);

    if (sec < 10) {
      sec = "0" + sec;
    }

    var message = min + ":" + sec; 

    timeDisplay.innerHTML = message; 

    if (secondsRemaining === 0) {
      alert("Done!");
      clearInterval(intervalHandle);
      resetPage();
    }
    // subtracts seconds remaining
    secondsRemaining--;

  }

  function startCountdown() { 

    var minutes = document.getElementById("minutes").value; 

    if (isNaN(minutes)) {
      alert("Please enter a number");
      return;
    }

    if (minutes == "") {
      alert("Please enter a number");
      return;
    }

    secondsRemaining = minutes * 60;
    intervalHandle = setInterval(tick, 1000);

    document.getElementById("inputArea").style.display = "none";
  }

  window.onload = function() {

    var inputMinutes = document.createElement("input");
    inputMinutes.setAttribute("id", "minutes");
    inputMinutes.setAttribute("type", "text");

    var startButton = document.createElement("input");
    startButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
    startButton.setAttribute("value", "Start Countdown");
    startButton.onclick = function() {
      startCountdown();
    };

    document.getElementById("inputArea").appendChild(inputMinutes);
    document.getElementById("inputArea").appendChild(startButton);
  };
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<title>Countdown</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="inputArea"></div>
  <h1 id="time">0:00</h1>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 100%
  color: rgb(33, 33, 33);
}

#container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

#time {
  font-size: 100px;
}


.red {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Use the inspect element feature of your browser to see if the class is being set

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea! There's just a small mistake in your code:

When you try to set `timeDisplay.className`, don't forget to add a space before the new class you're trying to add — otherwise it would append incorrectly.

Consider:

```
"oldClass" + "red" // => "oldClassred"    bad
// vs.
"oldClass" + " red" // => "oldClass red"  good
```

So you just need to add a space before `red` here:

Another typo was your equality comparison: `<==` should just be `<=`.

```
if (secondsRemaining <= 10) {
  timeDisplay.className += " red";
}
```

Comment: @userSufyan Glad I could help!